# adding element dynamically from javascript

Tags: javascript, html

all,

How to create an element in javascript, say `<div></div>` and i want to assign a javascript value to it say `var a=3`;

Example:

```
<script>
var ele=create element('<div>');
ele.add(a)
</div>
</script>
```

Thanks..........

Comment: this question is not very clear at all. what does it even mean, to you, to assign a javascript value to a html element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new, W3C approved way is to use [`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.createElement) for creation and  [`Node.appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.appendChild) or [`Node.insertBefore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.insertBefore) to add the new node as a child of another. These functions are defined by the [DOM level 1 standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/).

To add text to a node, create it with [`document.createTextNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createTextNode), then add the text node using one of the previously mentioned methods. To change the text in a text node, assign to the text node's [`nodeValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.nodeValue) property.

```
// create the element
var elt = document.createElement('div');
// create & add text to the element
elt.appendChild(document.createTextNode('foo'));
// add the element to the body as the middle child
document.body.insertBefore(elt, document.body.childNodes[document.body.childNodes.length >> 1]);
...
// change the text stored in the element
elt.firstChild.nodeValue='bar';
```

Comment: DOM 1 came out in 1998. I don't think it qualifies as 'new' any longer :)

Comment: Try telling that to the `innerHTML` crowd.

Answer (score 0):

```
var el = document.createElement('div');
el.innerHTML = '3';
document.body.appendChild(el);
```